# When is Kernel updates gone work again?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Since Kernel 4.2.0-18 update none kernels work and I must set them in grub to 4.2.0-16, otherwise computer just doesn't work when I try to boot. It just stays at the login screen in lower resolution that the screen has. I can't log in with it. So I all the time set the default grub startup to Ubuntu with Kernel 4.2.0-16. When can I excpect to have working version or is it that I must do something myself to fix this issue?
Thanks in advice!:)

[Specific Information]

- Ubuntu Version: 15.10 64-bit
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i3-3240 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4
- GPU: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2
- HDD: 485,8 GB
- RAM: 5.8 GiB
- /boot/grub/grub.cfg: http://www.pasteall.org/62765
- uname -a: `Linux user-desktop 4.2.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 8 15:35:06 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- /etc/default/grub: http://www.pasteall.org/62766

Comment: I have no clue what are you talking about honestly. Pls elaborate your question with some more specs and details so we can help you (i.e. your grub details, uname -a and so on). if the kernel ver is available in ubuntu repo it means it should work and if it doesn't that means you did something wrong on your own, not that the kernel doesn't work. so provide more info pls. thx

Comment: I added the information you required.

Comment: Are you using one of the alternate drivers for your graphics card?  Can you try booting into one of the newer kernels using the `nomodeset` kernel option?

Comment: I am using the latest NVIDIA binary driver for my card(352.63). I don't know what is `nomodeset`. Is it something done through terminal? Is it safe for comuter?

Comment: @karel I don't want to stop the updates, I want to fix them...

Comment: You don't have to stop the updates, just interrupt them for a while. After a few months you might get a kernel update that works, and then you can skip forward over all the kernel updates that didn't work and your kernel updates can be continued normally from then on.

Comment: How can I know when it comes? How can I know if a kernel update will work?

Comment: Try installing a new kernel every once out of every 5 kernel updates until you get a kernel that works. I did this once when I was using Ubuntu 12.04, it took me about 3 months to get it sorted, and after that the problem was solved for good. I was also using a GeForce GT 610 graphics card at the time.

Comment: OK! I should just check the latest kernel each time, right? And if it works - set it to use "Ubuntu" instead of "Advanced Options for Ubuntu > Kernel Version"? Oh, and the GeForce GT 610 - it is awful card, wouldn't reccomend anybody to buy it... Wanna get better one asap.

Comment: @karel What if I install `nvidia-352-updates` instead of `nvidia-352`? Would it change something? And if I install `Nouveau` would it than make latest Kernel boot successfully? Would it at least improve chances? And than I install binary drivers again. Tell me if this'd work.;)

Comment: Installing nvidia-352-updates probably wouldn't change much. nvidia-352-updates is an updated version of nvidia-352, which is less thoroughly tested than nvidia-352. nouveau is an open source package that is a built-in package in the Ubuntu default installation. It is included in Ubuntu so that your OS will still be able to boot, even if you mess up a proprietary Nvidia graphics driver. Regarding reinstalling the binary drivers, I have never tried this method, so I don't know if it would improve your chances or not.

Comment: It may also interest you to know that recently manufactured versions of the  GeForce GT 610 graphics card have different chips on their boards, which have been upgraded from those on previous GeForce GT 610 graphics cards.

Comment: My card is Gainward GeForce GT 610 which uses GF119 architecture. It has 1 GB VRAM.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1 - Install the new kernel 4.2.0-22**

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 - Uninstall NVIDIA drivers 352**

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

**Step 3 - Install NVIDIA drivers 358**

[(latest official stable drivers 358.16)](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/95921/en-us)
[Reference : Proprietary GPU Drivers](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Note : In case it doesn't work with `nouveau.modeset=0`, replace this parameter with `nomodeset`. Graphics drivers often are the source for these kind of problems. NVIDIA fixes bugs and improves their drivers with every new release - 358 drivers entered the final stage on November, 20 / 2015.

Clarification :

NVIDIA provides graphics drivers through different channels. The long-lived branch delivers the current stable drivers which also are included in the official Ubuntu repositories. The short-lived branch intermediately delivers the latest official drivers with bug fixes and improvements. These drivers are distributed through the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA and though they are stable, they are not officially tested on Ubuntu. This means, when you install them, you do it on your own risk.

Recommendation :

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. When you encounter problems with these drivers - you can install the more current drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA. This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on very new NVIDIA GEFORCE adapters.

Comment: hm... Will the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` make no trouble when upgrading to 16.04? Is it safe to do `purge nvidia*`? Can't it make my screen black?

Comment: @AdriansNetlis : When you want to upgrade to 16.04, you would have to remove the ppa before. However I recommend to perform a fresh install of the new Ubuntu LTS edition 16.04, because there will be many changes ... and purging the old nvidia drivers is safe, because you reinstall the new drivers afterwards. :)

Comment: But during the new driver installation would I have any image on screen? I mean - there will not be any drivers installed at the moment, if I get it all right what I see. And what does it mean if `modeset` doesn't work? How to see that it is true? Also, I don't prefer LTS, I want there to be `.10` versions installed aswell. And I've never performed fresh OS installs. I have no idea if I can break down my system accidently. I also have forgotten where I keep some specific important files. However, I'll have to do fresh install someday anyway, need to keep OS unpolluted...

Comment: Please stop suggesting everyone to install beta Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I will not revoke the downvote. 358 are NOT "latest official stable drivers ". You make a lot of trouble by suggesting them everywhere.

Comment: @Pilot6 : NVIDIA 358.16 drivers are the latest official drivers from the short-lived branch - I never did and never will suggest to install beta drivers ! I updated the answer to make clear that these are the latest official drivers. :)

Comment: They are available only in PPA as a deb. And they are not tested on Ubuntu. This kind of drivers should be recommended to install ONLY if there is no other option for some new adapters. This is not the case. And you made a dozen answers suggesting to install them to everyone.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis : During the whole process you perform all actions from a virtual console without a GUI. This is the best method to gain proper results. Please try out whether it works and you achieve what you asked for in your question : booting from the current kernel into a working desktop environment with a correct screen resolution. If this does not work, you easily can reinstall the drivers you are using now by following the same instructions . For all other things, like what happens when a new Ubuntu edition will be released ... feel free to post a new question. Now it's up to you ... :)

Comment: OK! Thanks! I will try it when I will have free time

Comment: You can downvote any post you like. But please do not start this kinds of rant. It is not interesting to anyone.